# error when trying to import ps file by grImport in R

Tags: pdf, r, postscript

I need to create a *pdf* file with several chart created by `ggplot2` arranged in a A4 paper, and repeat it 20-30 times.

I export the `ggplot2` chart into *ps* file, and try to `PostScriptTrace` it as instructed in `grImport`, but it just keep giving me error of `Unrecoverable error, exit code 1`.

I ignore the error and try to import and *xml* file generated into R object, give me another error:

> attributes construct error
>   Couldn't find end of Start Tag text line 21
>   Premature end of data in tag picture line 3
>   Error: 1: attributes construct error
>          2: Couldn't find end of Start Tag text line 21
>          3: Premature end of data in tag picture line 3

What's wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you exporting as a .ps file, and then importing it with PostScriptTrace? Can't you save it directly as a .pdf with `pdf()`?

Comment: Agreed, it may be easier to use `pdf()`, or perhaps better yet, use `Sweave` to create your PDF output from R.

If you are not familiar with `Sweave` I recommend this tutorial: http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2010/02/getting-started-with-sweave-r-latex.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have no time to deal with [Sweave](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/), you could also write a simple TeX document from R after generating the plots, which you could later compile to pdf.

E.g.:

```
    ggsave(p, file=paste('filename', id, '.pdf'))
    cat(paste('\\includegraphics{',
        paste('filename', id, '.pdf'), '}', sep=''),
        file='report.pdf')
```

Later, you could easily compile it to pdf with for example pdflatex.